# Convert JSON To Particular JSON format through jquery

Tags: jquery, json

This is my JSON input. I want to append data object before every object and convert into particular format given below. Also any plugins available for same will do.Convert JSON into particular format

```
  [  
    {  
  "guid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
  "companyGuid":"12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
  "parentLocationGuid":null,
  "name":"location1",
  "description":"test",
  "isActive":true,
  "row_num":2,
  "children":[  
     {  
        "guid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE1",
        "companyGuid":"12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
        "parentLocationGuid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
        "name":"child location",
        "description":"test child",
        "isActive":true,
        "row_num":1,
        "children":[  

        ]
     }
  ]
  }
  ]
```

I want output as :

```
   [  
    {  
  "data":{  
     "guid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
     "companyGuid":"12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
     "parentLocationGuid":null,
     "name":"location1",
     "description":"test",
     "isActive":true,
     "row_num":2
  },
  "children":[  
     {  
        "data":{  
           "guid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE1",
           "companyGuid":"12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
           "parentLocationGuid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
           "name":"child location",
           "description":"test child",
           "isActive":true,
           "row_num":1
        },
        "children":[  

        ]
     }
  ]
}
]
```

Comment: And what did you try ?

Comment: Tried to loop around it and append to data object but not getting required result. May b i am missing something

Comment: You should parse the json and create your object from that.

Comment: I posted an answer that gives your ouput. Please let me know if it's what you wanted.

Comment: _“May b i am missing something”_ - yes, you are missing that asking for suggestions for plugins etc. is off-topic here, and that this is not a code-writing service, so you should at least show us what you have tried so far. Please go read [ask] in that regard.

Comment: Plus, that you should not ask the same low-quality question again, after your previous one was rightfully closed for being too broad. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189128/convert-flat-json-to-parent-child-json-structure-upto-n-level-in-angular-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ES6 implementation of what you're trying to make. This is adaptable to lists containing more than one element.

```
function formatter(input){
    let output = new Array();
    input.forEach( data_input=>{
      let result = {};
      let children = [];
      result['data'] = {};
      Object.keys(data_input).forEach(key => {
       if (data_input[key] instanceof Object ){
         if(!(data_input[key] instanceof Array && data_input[key].length===0 )) 
         children = data_input[key];
       }
       else{
        result['data'][key] = data_input[key]
       }
    })
      result['children'] = formatter(children);
      output.push({'data': result['data']},{'children': result['children']})
    })
 return output
}

let myInput = [  
    {  
  "guid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
  "companyGuid":"12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
  "parentLocationGuid":null,
  "name":"location1",
  "description":"test",
  "isActive":true,
  "row_num":2,
  "children":[  
     {  
        "guid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE1",
        "companyGuid":"12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
        "parentLocationGuid":"6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
        "name":"child location",
        "description":"test child",
        "isActive":true,
        "row_num":1,
        "children":[  

        ]
     }
  ]
  }
  ]



console.log(formatter(myInput))
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. Actually i need data object to be compled before children node starts. In this case data object contains both parent and children. I need parent and child nodes in different data object. Please help..

Comment: Edited, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy using ES6 deconstruction and spread operator

```js
const res = data.map(({children,...otherProps})=>({data:{...otherProps}, children}));

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
  var data = [{
    "guid": "6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
    "companyGuid": "12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
    "parentLocationGuid": null,
    "name": "location1",
    "description": "test",
    "isActive": true,
    "row_num": 2,
    "children": [{
      "guid": "6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE1",
      "companyGuid": "12A5CD86-F6C6-455F-B27A-EFE587ED410D",
      "parentLocationGuid": "6FCBBB6B-4B5E-42C4-B108-12F594DABEE2",
      "name": "child location",
      "description": "test child",
      "isActive": true,
      "row_num": 1,
      "children": [

      ]
    }]
  }]
</script>
```

Comment: i need data object within children nodes also .. In all N level children nodes